# Why is this inner product equal to $0$?

Tags: analysis, inner-products

Why is / how can I show that

$$ \Big\langle f - \sum_{k=-N}^N\langle f, e_k\rangle, \sum_{k=-N}^N(\langle f, e_k\rangle-a_k)e_k\Big\rangle = 0?$$

Here the $e_k$ are functions $e_k(x)=e^{2\pi i k x}$, $f\in L_p([0, 1]), a_k\in \mathbb{C}$, and the inner product is defined as $$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{[0, 1]}f\bar g$$

Comment: $\sum_{k=-N}^N\langle f, e_k\rangle$ is a scalar!

Comment: @Cesareo I am drawing a blank, unable to think of the relevant property that when used in conjunction with what you pointed out should make the expression reduce to zero. Can you help me out some more, please?

Comment: What is $a_k$ ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien Any complex number.

Comment: Basically people are saying you most likely made a mistake in your formula, it should be $\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k$ on the left-hand side.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thank you for making it clear for me. I wasn't thinking of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_N=\sum_{k=-N}^N \langle f,e_k\rangle e_k$,
$$\left\langle f-S_N,S_N-\sum_{k=-N}^N a_ke_k\right\rangle=\langle f,S_N\rangle-\sum_{k=-N}^N a_k\langle f,e_k\rangle-\langle S_N,S_N\rangle+\sum_{k=-N}^Na_k\langle S_N,e_k\rangle$$
But $\langle S_N,e_k\rangle=\langle f,e_k\rangle$ thus
$$ \left\langle f-S_N,S_N-\sum_{k=-N}^N a_ke_k\right\rangle=\langle f,S_N\rangle-\langle S_N,S_N\rangle $$
and $$ \langle S_N,S_N\rangle=\sum_{k=-N}^N \langle f,e_k\rangle^2=\langle f,S_N\rangle $$
Finally $\left\langle f-S_N,S_N-\sum_{k=-N}^N a_ke_k\right\rangle=0$

Comment: But the first component of the IP isn't $f - S_N$.

Comment: It must be, $f-\sum_{k=-N}^N \langle f,e_k\rangle$ makes no sense, $f$ is a function and $\sum_{k=-N}^N \langle f,e_k\rangle$ is a scalar... You forgot to put the $e_k$'s (you put it in the right side).

Comment: Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

$$
\Big\langle f - \sum_{k=-N}^N\langle f, e_k\rangle e_k, \sum_{k=-N}^N(\langle f, e_k\rangle-a_k)e_k\Big\rangle
$$

we have

$$
\langle f,\sum \langle f,e_k\rangle e_k\rangle  - \langle f,\sum a_k e_k\rangle  -\langle\sum\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k,\sum\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k\rangle  + \langle\sum \langle f,e_k\rangle e_k,a_k e_k\rangle 
$$

or

$$
\sum \langle f,e_k\rangle^2-\sum a_k\langle f,e_k\rangle  -\sum \langle f,e_k\rangle^2+\sum a_k\langle f,e_k\rangle  = 0
$$